# Alter auto-increment of table with 16 million rows

Tags: mysql, myisam, alter-table, auto-increment

Learned this the hard way. Need to alter a table's auto-increment with 16 million rows.

Now, it's taking quite sometime.

Any estimate how long it would take? Sorry.

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable\G` and post the output (you can hide sensitive columns if you wish).

Comment: 2.5 hours on aws rds, medium size server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two things I learned here.

1. Insert a record, and edit the last insert id.
2. Alter table auto-increment, which will take sometime.

It's better to just deal with the problem using #1

Comment: What do you mean by #1? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hi. #1 - Insert a record, and edit the last insert id.

Comment: That's not elaborating. That's repeating. I still have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, could be an hour or so. Perhaps you may like to give percona toolkit a try; `pt-online-schema-change`.

```
pt-online-schema-change alters a table’s structure without blocking reads or writes.
Specify the database and table in the DSN. Do not use this tool before reading its
documentation and checking your backups carefully.
```

Source: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html

Comment: Not sure if it helps with aut increment, if python's more your thing, you could look [here](http://code.openark.org/forge/openark-kit).